# Created_at or updated_at not displaying full dateTime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my laravel app i need to compare 2 dateTime, the created_at and the updated_at, but i notice that when i call this properties of the record is not disaplayed the seconds, onlu hour and minutes, i need to get the seconds, what i need to change or include to show all info? I beend checking on the documentation and didnt found anything.

Ex:

```
$calculation->created_at
```

output:

```
2017-03-03 21:03
```

And in database is:

```
2017-03-03 21:03:22
```

Comment: Is this a fresh Laravel install? The default display for timestamps is `Y-m-d H:i:s` [per the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

Comment: is laravel 5.1 version

Comment: The default [is the same for Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators) and, as far as I'm aware, all version of Laravel.

Comment: Did you create these columns with timestamps() in your migration? Because it is strange stuff, imho, for the format to change suddenly beyond the default settings. And maybe use the format method on the Carbon date for now: "$calculation->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');"

Answer (score 0):

What the string output is doesn't effect what the value of the object is. You simply need to compare the two objects to each other.

```
$dateFromDB = $row['date'];
$compareDateTime = new DateTime('1999-12-31');  // some date

if($compareDateTime < srttotime($dateFromDB))
{
   // do stuff...
}
```

Note the use of strtotime function. This converts a string to a unix timestamp (which is what a DateTime object is under the hood).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

In your model, try to add:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

this will make them Carbon instances and you should be able to some something like this:

```
if($calculation->created_at == $calculation->updated_at)
```

Or any other thing you would do.

Answer (score 0):

`created_at` and `updated_at` are intances of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php), the `__toString()` of a Carbon instance returns the [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) formatted as `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Sources:

- [Laravel Eloquent: Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)
- [Carbon documentation: String Formatting](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)
- [Carbon.php on Github](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php#L119)
- [PHP: date](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)